# axis y line*=right does not move ylabel to right

Tags: pgfplots

When I recompile this code from the [pgfplots gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) (example_291.tex), I get the following graph which clearly does not move the `ylabel` to the right for the second `axis`
[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ scale only axis, xmin=-5,xmax=5, 
    axis y line*=left, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=Absolute] 
    \addplot {x^2}; 
    \end{axis} 

    \begin{axis}[ scale only axis, xmin=-5,xmax=5,
     ymin=0,ymax=1000, yticklabel= {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\textperthousand}, 
     axis y line*=right, axis x line=none,
     ylabel style={font=\tiny}, ylabel=per thousand] 

    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I tried to change the style of the `ylabel` to investigate it to the boundaries of my pgf knowledge. It changed the font to `tiny` but still the `ylabel` is at left.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compile your code, you get this warning:

> Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode
>   (unsuitable t ick labels; missing features). Consider writing
>   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10} into your preamble.  on input line 5.

For more details on compatibility please read `pgfplots` manual, section 2.2 Upgrade remarks, page 8 (in my copy)

Solution: You have to add the `compat` option to `\pgfplotsset`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}   %% <-- this added
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale only axis,
xmin=-5,
xmax=5,
axis y line*=left,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=Absolute]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
scale only axis,
xmin=-5, xmax=5,
 ymin=0, ymax=1000,
 yticklabel= {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\textperthousand},
 axis y line*=right,
 axis x line=none,
 ylabel style={font=\tiny},
 ylabel=per thousand]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To be on safer side, it is advisable to add the current version in `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` for if you add `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` some thing may not work/break.

Comment: `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` works for me, but if I try `compat=1.10`, it says unknown pgf key.
Anyway. Problem solved. TX a lot.

Comment: @antmw1361 It means you don't have version 1.10, may be older. Why not update? Glad it works but beware of `newest` option!